# Toward vs. Towards

Tags: word-choice, dialect

Are the words "toward" and "towards" synonymous?  If not, when should I use one over the other?  "Towards" usually sounds silly to my ear, but is that just me?

Comment: This is usually an AE vs BE difference. Actually toward sounds awkward to me.

Comment: As far as I know, the choice between these two words is mostly a matter of where you live. Generally speaking, UK and US people use, respectively, towards and toward. However, I'm not a native speaker of English language; so I might be wrong.

Comment: If *towards* sounds "silly" to you, just use *toward* in your own speech and writing. But it would be ill-advised to tell someone else their usage sounds silly. It's just regional variation (primarily a US/UK split), but there's a certain amount of "personal taste". Myself, I use both freely, but as a Brit I probably favour *towards*.

Comment: towards usual in australia

Comment: I don't suppose there's any etymological connection, but I can't resist pointing out that *crabs move **sideways*** (and I never heard of *a crab moving **sideway*** :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [*-ward*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=versus&allowed_in_frame=0) root in words like *forward*, *backward* or *toward* is related to the Latin [*vertere* and *versus*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=versus&allowed_in_frame=0) (to turn) and goes as far back as Sanskrit (*vartate*).

So this root has a rich history and has appeared in various altered forms in numerous Indo-European languages.

In German we have *wärts* which has the *s*: *rückwärts* (backward(s)) and *vorwärts* (forward(s)).

Evidently, in Old English the *-ward* root was either *-weard* or *-weardes*. So even in ancient times, there were already two forms: one with an *es* and one without. The idea that Brits use *-wards*, whereas *-ward* is a modern Americanism simply does not hold water since both versions trace back to respective Old English forms.

In any case, there is no need to have any qualms about putting the *s* on *-ward* or about leaving it off.

Comment: Certainly the modern usage of one form over the other can be regional, but I appreciate this short history lesson!

Comment: I think that not only is it one versus the other regional, but in some dialects *-wards* seems to refer only to a manner of motion, where *-ward* is more general. You can move *towards* a goal (or *toward*), but you turn *toward* your friends for help.  You also cannot *look forwards* to your vacation, only *forward*, but you can drive *forwards* and you can know something *forwards and backwards*.

Answer (score 29):

Indeed it seems that it is a British vs American difference. Note the ngrams below.

British:
[image: British novels and periodicals]
American:
[image: American novels and periodicals]

Comment: What an interesting chart!

Comment: I love the American graph's X shape :P

Comment: This is pretty misleading. A survey of ten of my American friends' email over ten years shows a strong dominance of *towards* in these particular individuals.

Comment: A survey of *10* of your friends vs the massive sample size that this is taken from.

Comment: @tchrist I hope you're joking, but sadly I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @carlo_R's comment and James Jiao's answer. However, towards isn't just limited to British English. For example, I grew up in the southern United States (Florida and Alabama to be exact) and say towards (my whole family does as well). Now, I live on the West coast United States and they generally say toward.

Comment: That's true, hence the word *chiefly* :P.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually an American vs British English difference. *Toward* is chiefly American and *towards* is chiefly used in BE and most commonwealth countries. The former is foreign to my ears but obviously understood due to the proliferation of American media.

Comment: Disagree.  *Towards* is also American.

Comment: @tchrist Might want to look up the word 'chiefly'.