# An "s" at the end of "toward", "inward", "forward", "backward", "outward", "upward", "downward"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, american-english, adverbs, british-english

I hunger to know whether it's true that an "**s**" at the end of such adverb as "**inward**", "**forward**", "**backward**", "**outward**", "**upward**", "**downward**", and "**toward**" (as a preposition only) is a choice of British English only?

I was analyzing these words and noticed that without the "**s**" at the end the word is used as an adjective in Br.E, except for "**toward**" that seems to be archaic as adjective.

- I was going **forward** *(Am.E)*
- I was going **forwards** *(Br.E)*

But

- It was a **forward** attack *(Both Am.E and Br.E since **forwards** is incorrect as an adjective)*

**Are my presumed assumptions correct?**

Comment: _I hunger to know_? I hope you are not Holofernes, are you?

Comment: Nope, I'm Russian. I just often use those words and wish to finally find out whether I can use them without the "**s**" at the end when speaking to British people and Americans alike.

Comment: Pretty similar question with good answers that might help: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/744/51806