# Should I write "toward" or "towards" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Mary peered at the red counter. And sure enough he stood there,
>   craning his stick-thin neck **toward(s)** her direction, squinting his
>   non-existent eyes at her.

Should it be **toward** or **towards**? And why?

Comment: I think people would use "craning his stick-thin neck in her direction" or "craning his stick-thin neck toward(s) her". But not "toward(s) her direction".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Toward* is more common in American English. *Towards* is more common in British English. See [Toward vs. Towards](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/744/toward-vs-towards)

In your example sentence, it's much more natural to use either *toward/s her* or *in her direction.*